# PowerShell: Parsing Through XML with the name "ADDRESS"

Tags: xml, powershell

XML:

```
<ServerList>
<ServerInfo ServerType="text" RPCServerPort="111" Port="110" Address="Server01" Name="Name1">
<ServerInfo ServerType="text" RPCServerPort="111" Port="110" Address="Server02" Name="Name2">
```

When I try to navigate in XML as such, it works:

```
[xml]$results = Get-Content C:\Users\myself\Desktop\file.xml
$results.ServerList.ServerInfo
```

Also:

- This works: `$results.ServerList.Name`
- This works: `$results.ServerList.Port`
- This works: `$results.ServerList.RPCServerPort`

However, this doesn't work: `$results.ServerList.Address`

I am getting a *OverloadDefinitions* result which has nothing to do with the content of the XML.

'Address' seems to do try to do something else, does anyone knows how to list the ADDRESS content in the XML ?

Comment: `$results.ServerList.ServerInfo|% Address` or `$results.ServerList.ServerInfo|Select -Expand Address` both work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays have a method known as Address defined in the CIL for retrieving items in the array.

```
$results.ServerList.ServerInfo.Address

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
System.Object&, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Address(int )
```

In this case when you call Address you assume PowerShell should retrieve each items' Address property, but PowerShell is returning the definition for the Address method of the array that contains those items.

If you want to access the properties you will need to change the property names so that they no longer match a method signature or loop through the items in the array and retrieve the properties the way TheMadTechnician suggested.

```
$results.ServerList.ServerInfo | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Address
$results.ServerList.ServerInfo | Foreach-Object {$_.Address}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me understand the vocabulary

Comment: I have a follow up question, how would I browse into each of the <ServerInfo> sub-items? each of the ServerInfo have more collapsible items under them. How do I choose into which ServerInfo I wish to drill.

Comment: Sorry. My question above is badly phrased and I can't change it:  
I have a follow up question, can I drill into each of the <ServerInfo> item with the syntax we used above? for example, I want to keep drilling into the <ServerInfo> item only if that comes from the <ServerInfo> which has Address="Server02"

Comment: It's cool I found it: need to use xpath with ServerInfo[contains(@Address, 'Server02')]